# Load partial view by sending javascript data array as parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my javascript to load partial view by sending a data array as a parameter.

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-add-answer', function () {       


    var answerObj = Array.from(GetAnswerDetails(this));
    var lastAnswer = answerObj[answerObj.length - 1];
    var answers = {};
    answers.Id = parseInt(lastAnswer.Id) + 1;
    answers.FormQuestionId = lastAnswer.FormQuestionId;
    answers.Text = "";
    answers.IsCorrect = false;
    answers.Score = null;
    answers.QuestionAnswerId = 0;
    answers.Sequence = 0;
    answerObj.push(answers);


    $("#survey-answer-container")
        .load("LoadTest", answerObj);

});
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult LoadTest(List<AnswerDto> answers)
        {

            return PartialView("_SurveyPageSectionQuestionAnswer", answers);
        }
```

And this is my DTO

```
public class AnswerDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        public bool? IsCorrect { get; set; }
        public int? Score { get; set; }
        public int FormQuestionId { get; set; }
        public int QuestionAnswerId { get; set; }
    }
```

The issue is the parameter didn't get to the controller. The 'answers' parameter in the controller will only have default values.

How to send data array from javascript as a parameter in partial view load?

Comment: You are explicitly replacing the values of the DTO on the controller...

Comment: @Gusman that was my test data actually.. forgot to delete it.. but the issueremain the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your object like below. Wrap your `object` as `{ answers: answerObj }` so it could match with parameter name.

```
$("#survey-answer-container")
    .load("LoadTest", { answers: answerObj });
```